# Writing text on "div" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble whenever I want to add some text to my div tag, here's my code:

```
<html>

<body>
<div id="comments">

</div>
<form name="forma">
<textarea name="commentUser" id="commentUser" cols="40" rows="5">
Comments here...
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment()" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function writeComment()
    {
    var comment = document.forma.commentUser.value;
    alert(comment);

    document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML=comment;


    }


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

It does what it has to do correctly, but then it switches back to the text box only and the comment I just wrote disappears. Any idea of what's going on here?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is because you are submitting the form.

Quick fix:

```
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment()" />
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment()" />
```

In addition, you are able to prevent the default action of an input. Basically telling the browser the you are going to handle the action with [**preventDefault**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault):

```
function writeComment(e) {
    var comment = document.forma.commentUser.value;
    alert(comment);

    document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = comment;
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this method strip all HTML elements? If you want to send a text that is `<div>X</div><br/><div class='flight'></div>`, the element can't receive the text as it is?

Answer (score 5):

What's happening is your form is submitting, the page is refreshing, and the div is going back to its pre-JavaScript-set content.

Try swapping the type='submit' to 'button' on the button.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the submit button the form is submitted, causing the whole page to reload. You need to return false from the onclick of the submit button to prevent it:

```
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onclick="writeComment(); return false;" />
```

Or, if you don't want the button to ever submit the form change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`.

PS. It's bad practice to use the onclick attribute. Instead bind a handler to the click event using pure JS.

Comment: even due you are right about it being a bad practice, clearly the OP is a newbie to JS and asking him to do so, well, it will just make him more confused.

Comment: @Dementic Just letting him know. It's never to early to start using good practices. I don't think it's any more confusing to bind an event handler to an element than to use an onclick attribute.

Comment: My mom told me, when i was really little, that i need to learn to walk before i can run. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use not just a regular button  but a submit button which by default submits the form to the server. You can see that your comment is submitted via URL as you didn't specify the method(GET and POST and GET is default).

Simply write:

```
onclick="writeComment();return false;"
```

Returning FALSE prevents from default behaviour - submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Its making another request to the server, which is causing the page to be rendered again.

Just return false from `writeComment`.

Comment: returning false from writeComment won't do anything unless he changes his onclick to `return writeComment();` He needs to return false from the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to prevent your form from submitting:

```
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment()" />
```

to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment(); return false;" />
```

Comment: btw, James hill is right,
if you will want to add more then one comment,
you will have to do +=

Answer (score 0):

try `<input type="button" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment()" />`

Answer (score 0):

you should switch 
`<input type="submit" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment()" />` 
for 
`<input type="button" value="Ready!" onClick="writeComment()" />`

Answer (score 0):

Or another option is to convert your `submit` into a `button` and take it out of the form, buttons can now exist outside of forms and from the code you pasted I don't see why you have to use a form, this will mean that your page isn't reloaded when you click on the "Ready" button.