# Phonegap not able to make ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I am calling a javascript function that makes ajax call on onclick of button, code is:

```
<button onclick="getTextValue()" id="pass_text_values" >Submit</button>
```

Javascript function is:

```
function getTextValue() 
{
  var user_postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;
  alert("postcode value entered by user = "+user_postcode);

  var brand_id = document.getElementById('getBrand').value;
  alert("entered value of brand = "+brand_id);

  var product_type_id = document.getElementById('getProductType').value;
  alert("entered value of brand = "+product_type_id);

  remoteCall(user_postcode, brand_id, product_type_id); 
  //document.getElementById("pass_text_values").onclick =  remoteCall('m14', 1, 1);

}//end of func to get textfield value().
```

remotecall function makes ajax call to server and displays data, code is:

```
function remoteCall(postcode, brand_id, product_type_id)
{


try
{

  alert("values Inside TRY:\n Postcode = "+postcode+"\n Brand = "+brand_id+"\n                 Product type = "+product_type_id);
  var serverUrl = "http://192.168.1.200/kruthika/findenggapi.php?postcode_s="+postcode+"&brand_id="+brand_id+"&product_type_id="+product_type_id;
  alert("URL : \n "+serverUrl);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: serverUrl ,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data == '')
          alert("No data received from server");
        else
        { 
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            { 
                var disp_data = "name = "+data[i].name+"<br> town = "+data[i].town+"<br> phone = "+data[i].phone+"<br> mobile = "+data[i].mobile+"<br> Email = "+data[i].email+"<hr>";
                alert("Data from server = "+disp_data);

            }

        }//end of else.
    },//ens od success.        
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert('FAIL !!!');
    },

});//end of AJAX.


}//end of try
catch(e)
{
    alert("error = "+e.message); 
}

}//END OF FUNC remoteCall.
```

If i call the same remotecall function outside then it works but if i call it with onclick it is not working. Can anyone help.

Comment: Are you sure that var user_postcode, brand_id and product_type_id are good ? What is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the option

```
async:false
```

to you ajax call.. It might work then.

Comment: :Thank you sooooo much..... :) I am able to get output now. I am able to alert the result. But i want the result in <div>. I have added this code for that:          document.getElementById("engg_details").innerHTML = final_disp_data; but its not working... can u help in this pls....

Comment: try this... this might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195844/writing-text-on-div-using-javascript

and don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Thanks man, u made my day...... :) thanks alot... :)              <button onclick="getTextValue();return false;" >Submit</button> ,this solved my problem.... :)